# Only setting the initial region on a react-native MapView

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

*Use case:* Annotations are displayed on a map, using the react-native MapView component. The initial map region is set so that all of the annotations are visible. Annotations are moving around, which triggers re-renders. In addition, the user should be able to pan/zoom around the map, so `onRegionChange()` and `onRegionChangeComplete()` attempt to capture region changes and set those in the state; in this way, the map region doesn't reset to the initial map region whenever a re-render occurs.

```
render: function() {
  ...
  return (
    <MapView
      region={this.state.region}
      annotations={annotations}
      onRegionChange={this.onRegionChange}
      onRegionChangeComplete={this.onRegionChangeComplete}
    />
  );
},

onRegionChange: function(region) {
  this.setState({ region });
},

onRegionChangeComplete: function(region) {
  this.setState({ region });
},
```

*Problem:* Setting the updated region in the state doesn't allow for a smooth panning/scrolling experience on the map, due to the delay in updating the state. After a couple of pans or zooms, the map freezes, presumably because it is using the current region saved in the state, and not a more updated region. Wait 1-2 seconds, and the map can be panned/zoomed again, presumably because the region has now been updated in the state.

*Question:* Is there a way to set the MapView's initial region only, such that a re-render doesn't cause the region to reset? That way, `onRegionChange()` and `onRegionChangeComplete()` can be used as delegate methods to perform work on the new region (analogous to MKMapViewDelegate's mapView:regionWillChangeAnimated:), rather than saving the region itself for the purposes of map rendering.

Answer (score 4):

region is an attribute for demos only, don't use and do not need to use it for real life...
[try this method in real life(example)](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/f553317fcaa2e3a4889f38c4bb2e215693f3f20c/example/examples/DisplayLatLng.js)

take mine relocate button of animate back to users current location for eg:

```js
<MapView initialRegion = {...some init region} onRegionChangeComplete = {region=>this.setState({region} ref={ref=>this.map=ref}>
</MapView>

<TouchableOpacity onpress={this.onRelocate}><Text>back to my position</Text></TouchableOpacity>

onRelocate = () => {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      position => {
        Toast.loading("定位中...", 2);
        let region = {
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position.coords.longitude
        };
        this.map.animateToRegion(region)
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude animateToRegion was the key