# React native maps MapView Region not updating on MarkerDrag

Tags: react-native, google-maps, react-native-maps

I am trying to implement to search and pinpoint a location in react native. I am using `react-native-maps` and `react-native-google-places-autocomplete`  packages for their obvious usages.
First I have initiated region in the state as:

```
   constructor(){
    this.state={
         mapRegion: {
                        latitude: this.props.latitude ? this.props.latitude : 27.7172,
                        longitude: this.props.longitude ? this.props.longitude : 85.3240,
                        latitudeDelta: 0.005,
                        longitudeDelta: 0.005,
                    },
    }
    }
```

I have tried to update the region on pressing the autocompleted search results as well as upon marker drag. But I get an error as:

```
Error: You attempted to set the key latitude with the value '27' on an object that is meant to be immutable and has been frozen.
```

I have implemented the code as:

```
               <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
                            placeholder='Search'
                            fetchDetails={true}
                            onPress={(data, details = null) => {
                                let tempMapRegion = this.state.mapRegion;
                                tempMapRegion.latitude = details.geometry.location.lat;
                                tempMapRegion.longitude = details.geometry.location.lng;
                                this.setState({ mapRegion: tempMapRegion })
                            }}
                            query={{
                                key: AppSettings.googleMapApiKey,
                                language: 'en',
                            }}
                        />
                        <MapView
                            initialRegion={{
                                latitude: this.props.latitude ? this.props.latitude : 27.7172,
                                longitude: this.props.longitude ? this.props.longitude : 85.3240,
                                latitudeDelta: 0.005,
                                longitudeDelta: 0.005,
                            }}
                            region={this.state.mapRegion}
                            onRegionChange={(e) => { this.onRegionChange(e) }}
                            style={{ height: 300, width: 300 }}
                        >
                            <Marker draggable
                                coordinate={this.state.mapRegion}
                                onDragEnd={(e) => {
                                    let tempMapRegion = this.state.mapRegion;
                                    tempMapRegion.latitude = e.nativeEvent.coordinate.latitude
                                    tempMapRegion.longitude = e.nativeEvent.coordinate.longitude
                                    this.setState({ mapRegion: tempMapRegion })
                                }}
                            />
                        </MapView>
```

The `onRegionChange` in the `MapView` works smoothly and marker is dragged automatically to the centre, but the reverse process brings up the above error.

What is causing this error and how do I get past this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<View style={{ padding: 2, }}>
                            <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
                                placeholder='Search'
                                fetchDetails={true}
                                onPress={(data, details = null) => {
                                    let tempMapRegion = this.state.mapRegion;
                                    tempMapRegion.latitude = details.geometry.location.lat;
                                    tempMapRegion.longitude = details.geometry.location.lng;
                                    this.map.animateToRegion(this.newRegion(tempMapRegion));
                                    this.setState({ address: data.description })

                                }}
                                query={{
                                    key: AppSettings.googleMapApiKey,
                                    language: 'en',
                                }}
                            />
                        </View>
                        <MapView
                            provider={this.props.provider}
                            ref={ref => { this.map = ref; }}
                            mapType={MAP_TYPES.TERRAIN}
                            initialRegion={this.state.mapRegion}
                            onRegionChangeComplete={(e) => { this.onRegionChange(e) }}
                            style={{ height: width, width: width, marginTop: -5 }}
                        >
                            <Marker draggable
                                coordinate={this.state.mapRegion}
                                onDragEnd={(e) => {
                                    let tempMapRegion = this.state.mapRegion;
                                    tempMapRegion.latitude = e.nativeEvent.coordinate.latitude
                                    tempMapRegion.longitude = e.nativeEvent.coordinate.longitude
                                    this.map.animateToRegion(this.newRegion(tempMapRegion));
                                    // this.setState({ mapRegion: tempMapRegion })
                                }}
                            />
                        </MapView>
```

So, what basically did the thing, was using the `animateToRegion` property of the mapview. It basically animates the view to the mentioned region and then calls the `onRegionChange`. I had stumbled upon this answer a number if times but it hadnt worked. Weirdly this only works in the build version and not while debugging, not on the emulator at least.

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/53836679/5379191 this answer for showing the way though.

```
   newRegion(tempMapRegion) {
        return {
            ...this.state.mapRegion,
            ...this.regionCoordinate(tempMapRegion),
        };
    }

    regionCoordinate(tempMapRegion) {
        return {
            latitude: tempMapRegion.latitude,
            longitude: tempMapRegion.longitude,
        };
    }
```